# How to update previous records without updating max record in Netezza

Tags: sql, timestamp, max, netezza

Hoping someone can be of assistance.  I am trying to do an update statement. I have a table that has the columns:
`BUS_NBR_SK, BUS_NBR, EFF_DT, ENT_TMPSTP, EXP_DT`.

Primary keys are `BUS_NBR_SK` and `BUS_NBR`.  There is only one table here.

These are inserts into a table and I need to update the `EXP_DT` on the older records and leave the most recent one alone by using the `max(ENT_TMSTP)` I was going to just do an update with a `SET b.EXP_DT = current_timestamp` where `EXP_DT IS NULL` however that won't work because the most recent record will also be assigned an expire date.

Any ideas how that could work?

I have tried the following but it was updating everything with the max effective date.

```
UPDATE TABLE b
SET b.EXP_DT = (SELECT MAX(a.EFF_DT)
FROM TABLE A
INNER JOIN TABLE B
ON A.BUS_NBR_SK = B.BUS_NBR_SK
AND A.ENT_TMSTP = B.ENT_TMSTP
AND A.BUS_NBR = B.BUS_NBR)
WHERE EXP_DT IS NULL
and ENT_TMSTP != (select max(c.ENT_TMSTP)
from table C)
```

Thank you so much!

[example of the fields in the table with sample data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FagxB.gif)

Comment: Edit your question and tag it with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but using a correlated subquery will at least get the `set` logic correct:

```
UPDATE table b
    SET b.EXP_DT = (SELECT MAX(a.EFF_DT)
                    FROM TABLE A
                    WHERE A.BUS_NBR_SK = B.BUS_NBR_SK AND
                          A.ENT_TMSTP = B.ENT_TMSTP AND
                          A.BUS_NBR = B.BUS_NBR
                   )
    WHERE b.EXP_DT IS NULL AND
          b.ENT_TMSTP <> (SELECT MAX(c.ENT_TMSTP) FROM table C);
```

I'm not sure if this fixes your overall problem, though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response. I seem to be getting a syntax error:                                         ^ found "table" (at char 81) expecting `WITH' or `'(''

Comment: I think I'd just want to go the route and set the exp_date to be the current timestamp like so: 
UPDATE TABLE b
SET b.EXP_DT = current_timestamp  and avoid the most recent record from being updated.  I keep getting errors when trying to implement this.

Comment: @RoxanneLuick . . . The reference to `TABLE` is in your original query.  It is not part of the SQL syntax.  The table name should follow `FROM` with the alias after that.

Comment: I modified this and am getting a new error: sub-SELECT in FROM must have an alias.  I haven't used updates with subqueries very much before.    Here is my revised script:                                             UPDATE TABLE b
   SET b.EXP_DT = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  FROM (SELECT BUS_NBR_SK,
               BUS_NBR,
               max (ENT_TMSTP) AS max_ENT_TMSTP
          FROM TABLE a
         WHERE     A.BUS_NBR_SK = b.BUS_NBR_SK
               AND A.BUS_NBR = b.BUS_NBR) group
 by BUS_CARD_ENHANCED_ATTR_SK,BUS_ENTITY_SK
    WHERE b.EXP_DT IS NULL
    and ENT_TMSTP <> max_ENT_TMSTP

Comment: @RoxanneLuick . . .  This answer does not have two levels of subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update b.EXP_DT with the date at a.EFF_DT for the newest record for a specific key of BUS_NBR_SK, ENT_TMSTP and BUS_NBR you can create a Group by view for A or you can declare it inside the update query as shown below:

UPDATE table b
    SET b.EXP_DT = A_Group.Max_EFF
    FROM TABLE A INNER JOIN
    (SELECT BUS_NBR_SK, ENT_TMSTP, BUS_NBR, MAX(A.EFF) as Max_EFF
        FROM B 
        GROUP BY BUS_NBR_SK, ENT_TMSTP, BUS_NBR) AS A_Group ON
    A_Group.BUS_NBR_SK = b.BUS_NBR_SK AND
            A_Group.ENT_TMSTP = b.ENT_TMSTP AND
            A_Group.BUS_NBR = b.BUS_NBR
    WHERE b.EXP_DT IS NULL AND
        b.ENT_TMSTP <> (A_Group.Max_EFF);

Hope it helps.
Sergio

Comment: I modified this and am getting a new error: sub-SELECT in FROM must have an alias.  I haven't used updates with subqueries very much before.